# Add left and right margin to tableview of UITableViewController

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I have tableview of UITableViewController with static cells.

Now I want to add left and right margin constrain at the runtime because I can not add constrain using Interface Builder.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could embed a UITableView inside a UIView instead of the UIViewController. If you did this you could resize the tableview and set margins in the interface builder. Create a new UIViewController (one that doesn't have a UITableView included) then drag a new UITableView onto it. Remember to set the data source and delegate to the new UIViewController. That should do it.

[image: example here, it's just a blank view controller with the table view dragged on]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


        if(indexPath.row==0){
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"your text";
        return cell;
}



if(indexPath.row==1){
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.textLabel.text = @"your text2";
            return cell;
    }
```

etc...

Comment: Agreed, I find myself almost never using the UITableViewController due to the lack of control you'll have over the UI.

Comment: Yes. But Interface Builder give me error when I use static cell in tableview inside ViewController

Comment: perhaps you could just change your implementation and use dynamic then. if you are using static already then the data in your cells is likely to just be text and it's easy to change it to dynamic.

Comment: Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances

Comment: yeah, if you really want to go ahead and do it in the interface builder you can change it to dynamic easily enough.

Comment: I think it gives you more flexibility overall too

Comment: Than I have to create a prototyping cell for all static cell

Comment: it's just one cell that you replicate for all of them

Comment: All cell are different

Comment: you mean the text is different in the cells or the styling is difference? If it's static you must mean the text. You just use an if statement.

Comment: No. All cell contain different views

Comment: added an example using if statements above

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but May be - tableView's scrollview insets can help you-[image]